# Laravel search by dates not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to search by date. My route definition:

```
Route::get('/calendar/days?day={date}', 'HomeController@getDays');
```

[image]

In the controller method I have this:

```php
public function getDays($date)
{
    $articles = Article::where('published_at','=',$date)->get();
    dd($articles);
}
```

When you click on the link on the image below I get a **NotFoundHttpException**.

The link is generated using JS. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be defining query string parameters in the route definition. For a detailed explanation on why that is see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30558137/351330). So in your case you have two options:

**1.** Remove the `?day={date}` from the definition:

```php
Route::get('/calendar/days', 'HomeController@getDays');
```

And in your controller access the request input parameter like so:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function getDays(Request $request)
{
    $date = $request->input('date');
    $articles = Article::where('published_at', '=', $date)->get();
}
```

**2.** Modify your route definition to something like this:

```php
Route::get('/calendar/days/{date}', 'HomeController@getDays');
```

The controller code you have now needs no change in this case, however the link you generate via JavaScript would need to look like this:

```
<a href="/calendar/days/2015-04-09">9</a>
```

Comment: Thanks chose the second way)

Comment: That might be a separate issue. What is format of your `published_at` column in your database? Does it follow the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` like in your `where` condition? Because if it is `datetime` for example, it might be stored as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` which will not return any results if you pass it only the date.